# installing ckan with typo3

Tags: typo3, integration, ckan

I want to set up an open data website with the typo3 cms. For open data I do not know how I can manage with typo3. After a tour on google I found the CKAN API.
My questions: is it possible to integrate them? If not, are there any other solutions with Typo3?
Thank you for your possible answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know an implementation of the `CKAN API` and a quick search in the [TER (TYPO3 extension repository)](https://extensions.typo3.org) never showed any results.

Nevertheless there exists an extension `filemetadata` which is doing probably partially the requested features. Here the links:

1. [`filemetadata` on Packagist.org](https://packagist.org/packages/typo3/cms-filemetadata)
2. [`filemetadata` on github.com](https://github.com/TYPO3-CMS/filemetadata)

For the case that the features are not enough or the structure is not like desired a new extension could be programmed where some basics could be taken from the extension above, at least it could serve as example how some things are done.

It has to be mentioned that some extensions are never registered in TER but only available on github perhaps. So before programming something a deeper search might be advisable.
In former times another extension was common for Digital Asset Management, the extension-key and Name was `dam`. That extension is not compatible with current TYPO3 versions and taking it as example is probably no good idea as much outdated code had to be adjusted.
Nevertheless the advised example above is not the only possibility, the search for [`file metadata`](https://extensions.typo3.org/?L=0&id=1&tx_solr%5Bq%5D=file+metadata) still shows other extensions that are compatible to current TYPO3 versions 7 and 8 which could be taken as examples. Perhaps changed search-words still let you discover more useful extensions.

The mentioned extension in the top is supported by the TYPO3 core team, the others are provided by other developers. I never compared the extensions and you had to see code or/and features by yourself. So I never endorse any of these solutions as usage is rarely requested.

If you search for the most recent code it's always good to search on github first for the development branch or a release that is not (yet) published in TER. Another source of information is [forge.typo3.org](https://forge.typo3.org/projects/extensions), there many extensions are listed too, some even with repository on [git.typo3.org](https://git.typo3.org), perhaps it's worth it to mention that this source is abandoned by some developers in favor of github.

Technically it would be even possible to extend any found extension and add more features or change something just by another extension - without touching the original extension. But before thinking too far you should first have a look if any found extension could satisfy your needs already.

For further questions that might be already related to coding you should open new question(s) with more detailed explanation and code-examples, even if that doesn't work yet.

**EDIT 15th Oct 2018:**
Just got a hint about a helpful extension for those purposes: [extractor](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/extractor/). Additional fields shall go to sys_file_metadata and be a part of the extraction service.
As I never did verified it by myself I can't give further hints in the moment.

Comment: From your explainations I'll explore the extensions you proposed and see by myself if one of them satisfy my needs. CKAN is a Data Management System (DMS) based on Python language which can be used with some CMS like WordPress, Drupal,.. That's why I want to know if I can use it with Typo3.

Comment: ok, as it's in python you need a wrapper extension in php then. in the TYPO3-extension sphinx you can see how to make a wrapper for python.

Comment: to connect foreign data you also can have a look at the extension external_import, so there might be many ways how to realize it and many extensions where you could get ideas and some code-snippets.

Comment: Thanks David, I had a look at Typo3 extensions and I think that I can solve my situation using one of them. But I continue exploring other solutions before. If I get nothing good for my needs I'll see in typo3 extensions because I'm not using Python yet but PHP or Java

Comment: ok, I think `CKAN API` still is doing a bit something else than the extensions I mentioned. So it might be hard to find something existing doing exactly that in TYPO3 already. Surely PHP would be the easiest to implement or connect.

Comment: You're right, finally the team decided I use CKAN API. Thank you very much for contribution.